# What are the valid characters for macro names?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, c-preprocessor

Are C-style macro names subject to the same naming rules as identifiers?  After a compiler upgrade, it is now emitting this warning for a legacy application:

```
warning #3649-D: white space is required between the macro name "CHAR_" and its replacement text
  #define         CHAR_&        38
```

This line of code is defining an ASCII value constant for an ampersand.

```
#define   DOL_SN        36
#define   PERCENT       37
#define   CHAR_&        38
#define   RT_SING       39
#define   LF_PAR        40
```

I assume that this definition (not actually referenced by any code, as far as I can tell) is buggy and should be changed to something like "CHAR_AMPERSAND"?

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this: You can get ASCII values of characters in C by using single quotes: `'$'`, `'%'`, `'&'`, obviously things like `'&'+1` and `'&'+2` work as well (:

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Macro names should only consist of alphanumeric characters and underscores, i.e. `'a-z'`, `'A-Z'`, `'0-9'`, and `'_'`, and the first character should not be a digit.  Some preprocessors also permit the dollar sign character `'$'`, but you shouldn't use it; unfortunately I can't quote the C standard since I don't have a copy of it.

From the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html#Tokenization):

> Preprocessing tokens fall into five
>   broad classes: identifiers,
>   preprocessing numbers, string
>   literals, punctuators, and other. An
>   *identifier* is the same as an
>   identifier in C: any sequence of
>   letters, digits, or underscores, which
>   begins with a letter or underscore.
>   Keywords of C have no significance to
>   the preprocessor; they are ordinary
>   identifiers. You can define a macro
>   whose name is a keyword, for instance.
>   The only identifier which can be
>   considered a preprocessing keyword is
>   `defined`. See Defined.
>
> This is mostly true of other languages
>   which use the C preprocessor. However,
>   a few of the keywords of C++ are
>   significant even in the preprocessor.
>   See C++ Named Operators.
>
> In the 1999 C standard, identifiers
>   may contain letters which are not part
>   of the “basic source character set”,
>   at the implementation's discretion
>   (such as accented Latin letters, Greek
>   letters, or Chinese ideograms). This
>   may be done with an extended character
>   set, or the `'\u'` and `'\U'` escape
>   sequences. The implementation of this
>   feature in GCC is experimental; such
>   characters are only accepted in the
>   `'\u'` and `'\U'` forms and only if
>   `-fextended-identifiers` is used.
>
> As an extension, GCC treats `'$'` as a
>   letter. This is for compatibility with
>   some systems, such as VMS, where `'$'`
>   is commonly used in system-defined
>   function and object names. `'$'` is not
>   a letter in strictly conforming mode,
>   or if you specify the `-$` option. See
>   Invocation.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 6.10/1 specifies the grammar of preprocessing directives, making explicit that macro names share the exact same rules as identifiers. 6.4.2.1/1 specifies the rules for identifiers.

Answer (score 20):

`clang` allows a lot of "crazy" characters.. although I have struggled to find <strike>any</strike> much rhyme or reason - as to *why* **some** are allowed, and others are **not**.  For example..

```
#define   ?:          /// WORKS FINE
#define  ￭  @end        /// WORKS FINE
#define   @interface  /// WORKS FINE
#define Ｐ  @protocol   /// WORKS FINE
```

yet

```
#define ☎   TEL     /// ERROR: Macro name must be an identifier.
#define ❌   NO     /// ERROR: Macro name must be an identifier.
#define ⇧   UP      /// ERROR: Macro name must be an identifier.
#define 〓   ==     /// ERROR: Macro name must be an identifier.
#define   APPLE   /// ERROR: Macro name must be an identifier.
```

*Who knows.*  I'd love to... but Google has thus failed me, so far.  Any insight on the subject, would be appreciated™️.

Comment: Have a look into clang documentation. Or if it isn't even documented, check its sourcecode for it since its opensource. But By C standard I can tell you all of them are invalid. and therefor, since its not asked for any enviroment related req's, but for plain C. So this is even more fitting as a seperated Question as an answer and probably it should even be flagged as such. ... Even a pretty good one. I'm gonna ask this if you are not going to.

Comment: @Zaibis check out [What constitutes as “valid” C Identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34319000/547214)

Answer (score 8):

You're right, the same rules apply to macro and identifiers as far as the names are concerned: valid characters are [A-Za-z0-9_].

It's common  usage to use CAPITALIZED names to differentiate macros from other identifiers - variables and function name.

Answer (score 1):

The same rules that specify valid identifiers for variable names apply to macro names with the exception that macros may have the same names as keywords.  Valid characters in identifier names include `digits` and `non-digits` and must not start with a digit.  `non-digits` include the uppercase letters A-Z, the lowercase letters a-z, the underscore, and any implementation defined characters.

Comment: "with the exception that macros may have the same names as keywords" -- yes, but also with more exceptions that macros may not have the same name as this preprocessor keyword: defined