# What constitutes a "valid" C Identifier?

Tags: c, syntax, clang, naming-conventions, identifier

At @Zaibis suggestion (and related to my own *answer* to [What are the valid characters for macro names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34315237/547214), as well as  [(and other Unicode characters) in identifiers not allowed by g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/and-other-unicode-characters-in-identifiers-not-allowed-by-g)))...

> clang allows a lot of "crazy" characters.. although I have struggled to find much rhyme or reason - as to why some are allowed ( ϟ ツ ⌘ ☁ ½), and others are not (▶︎ ∀ ★ ©).

For example, the following all compile A-OK (`clang-700.1.76`)

```
#define   ?:          // OK (Pile of poo)
#define  ￭  @end        // OK (HALFWIDTH BLACK SQUARE)
#define   @interface  // OK (NEGATIVE SQUARED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K)
#define Ｐ  @protocol   // OK (FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P)
```

Yet the following all result in the same compiler error...

> `Macro name must be an identifier.`

```
#define  ☎     TEL
#define ❌     NO
#define  ⇧     UP
#define  〓    ==
#define     APPLE
```

[Clang's documentation refer to the issue](http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#major-new-features), stating only...

> ... support for extended identifiers in C99 and C++. This feature allows identifiers to contain certain Unicode characters, as specified by the active language standard; these characters can be written directly in the source file using the UTF-8 encoding, or referred to using universal character names (\u00E0, \U000000E0).

So, I guess I'm asking.. what *is* the "active language standard", and how can I find an authoritative source for what identifiers are legal.

I created the [following code](http://git.io/v01Pv) just to see what [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) would do with it.  Out of about 63488 possible identifiers tested, 23 issued warnings and 9506 generated errors.  That leaves almost 54,000 valid characters to use in identifiers.  Certainly enough, but who got cut? And why?

Comment: Related [Unicode/special characters in variable names in clang not allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26660180/1708801)

Comment: `@interface`, etc. do not look like valid C anyway. Does that happen to be Objective-C actually? If so, please update text and tags!

Comment: @Olaf I'm talking `C` identifiers.  [All valid `C` is valid `Objective-C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Syntax), so the superset of `C` is irrelevant.

Comment: That is not bijective. Can you prove Objective-C does not extend the definition of valid identifiers? Left that aside: Using non-ASCII identifiers is strongly deprecated; there is only one reson to use such eccentricities: to obfuscate the code. This includes language-specific characters like German Umlauts (`äöü`).

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Using non-ASCII identifiers is not deprecated in the computer science sense. It will be discouraged in many cases, but it can be useful for people who are only fluent in languages that need more than ASCII. (BTW, A-Z are language specific characters; the majority of people use languages that don't use A-Z.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As others have mentioned, Annex D of [ISO/IEC 9899:2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) lists the hexadecimal values of characters valid for universal character names in C11.  (I won't bother repeating it here.)  I have been searching for an answer as to "why" this list was chosen.

### Character set standards

First, there are two relevant standards defining a set of characters: [ISO/IEC 10646](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=63182) (defining [UCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set)) and [Unicode](http://unicode.org/).  To further confuse (or simplify) things, they both define *the same characters* since the ISO and Unicode keep them [synchronized](http://unicode.org/faq/unicode_iso.html).  UCS is essentially just a character map associating values to a set of characters ("repertoire"), while Unicode also gives further definitions such how to compare strings in an alphabetical sorting order ([collation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/)), which code points represent "canonically equivalent" characters ([normalization](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html)), and a [bidirectional algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/) for how to process characters in languages written right to left, and more.

### Universal character names in C

Universal character names (UCN) was a feature newly added in C99 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999).  In the "Rationale for International Standard---Programming Languages---C" ([Rev. 2, Oct. 1999](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n897.pdf)), the purpose was "to enable the use of any 'native' character in identifiers, string literals and character constants, while retaining the portability objective of C" (sec. 5.2.1).  This section continues on about issues of how to encode these characters in C (the `\U` and `\u` forms versus multibyte characters or native encodings) and policy models of how to deal with it (p.14, see [PDF](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n897.pdf) page 22).

### Rationale

I was hoping that the same ["rationale" document from 1999](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n897.pdf) would give a reason of why each extended character range was selected as acceptable for C99's UCNs.  The entirety of the rationale's Annex I is:

> **Annex I   Universal character names for identifiers (normative)**
>
> *A new feature of C9X.*

This is not much of a rationale.  They didn't even know what year the C standard would be published, so it's just called "C9X".  A later [rationale document from 2003](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) is slightly more enlightening:

> **Annex D   Universal character names for identifiers (normative)**
>
> *New feature for C99.*
>
> The intention is to keep current with ISO/IEC TR 10176.

[ISO/IEC TR 10176](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=37765) is "Guidelines for the preparation of programming language standards."  It a basically a guidebook for people who write programming language standards.  It includes guidelines for the use of character sets in programming languages as well as a "recommended extended repertoire for user-defined identifiers" (Annex A).  But this quote from the 2003 rationale document is only an "intention to keep current," not a pledge of strict adherence to TR 10176.

There is a publicly available [ISO/IEC TR 10176:2003 table](http://www.iso.org/ittf/ISOIEC_TR_10176_2003_Table.txt) of characters.  The character values refer to  ISO 10646.  The table classifies ranges of characters from numerous languages as being "uppercase" `Lu`; "lowercase" `Ll`; "number, decimal digit" `Nd`, "punctuation, connector" `Pc`; etc.  It should be clear what use such classifications have to a programming language.

An important reminder is that TR 10176 is a Technical Report, and not a standard.  I have found several passing references to it on forums and in documents related to other programming languages, such as Ada, COBOL, and D language.  Much of the discussion was about how closely standards of those languages should follow TR 10176 (not being a standard) and complaints that TR 10176 was lagging behind updates to ISO 10646.

Perhaps most enlightening is document [WG21/N3146](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3146.html): "Recommendations for extended identifier characters for C and C++."  It starts with a comment in 2010 to the standards body recommending restrictions on the initial characters of identifiers.  It mentions similar complaints about C referencing TR 10176, and makes suggestions about what characters should be allowed as initial characters of an identifier based on restrictions from [Unicode's Identifier and Pattern Syntax](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/tr31-11.html#Alternative_Identifier_Syntax) and [XML's Common Syntactic Constructs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn).  WG21/N3146 gives the proposed wording that later appeared in the C11 standard [ISO/IEC 9899:2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  There is a table at the end of the document that helps shed light on the character ranges selected.

### Characters allowed and not allowed in C11

Below is a compiled list of ranges for *extended* identifier characters.  The **boldface** ranges are those given in C11 ([ISO/IEC 9899:2011 Annex D](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).  Some comments are added about the *italicized* ranges *not listed in C11* (i.e. not allowed).  They are either marked in [WG21/N3146](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3146.html) as disallowed by [Unicode's UAX#31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/tr31-11.html#Alternative_Identifier_Syntax) or [XML's Common Syntactic Constructs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn), or prohibited by some other comment.

**00A8, 00AA, 00AD, 00AF, 00B2-00B5, 00C0-00D6, 00D8-00F6, 00F8-00FF**: (Various characters, such as feminine ª and masculine º ordinal indicators, vowels with diacritics, numeric characters such as superscript numbers, fractions, etc.)

*(previous gaps)*: All disallowed by [UAX31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/tr31-11.html#Alternative_Identifier_Syntax) and/or [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn).  (Generally punctuation type marks like «», monetary symbols ¥£, mathematical operators ×÷, etc.)

**0100-167F**: (Latin, Greek, Cyrillic, Arabic, Thai, Ethiopic, etc.---many others)

*1680*: "The Ogham block contains a script-specific space:  "

**1681-180D**: (Ogham, Tagalog, Mongolian, etc.)

*180E*: "The Mongolian block contains a script-specific space"

**180F-1FFF**: (More languages... phonetics, extended Latin & Greek, etc.)

*2000*: starts the "General Punctuation" block, but some are allowed:

**200B−200D, 202A−202E, 203F−2040, 2054, 2060−206F**: (selections from "General Punctuation" block)

**2070−218F**: "Superscripts and Subscripts, Currency Symbols, Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols, Letterlike Symbols, Number Forms"

*2190-245F*: "Arrows, Mathematical Operators, Miscellaneous Technical, Control Pictures, Optical Character Recognition"

**2460-24FF**: "Enclosed Alphanumerics"

*2500*: starts "Box Drawing, Block Elements, Geometric Shapes", etc.

**2776-2793**: (some dingbats and circled dingbats)

*2794-2BFF*: (a different dingbat set, mathematical symbols, arrows, Braille patterns, etc.)

**2C00-2DFF, 2E80-2FFF**: "Glagolitic, Latin Extended-C, Coptic, Georgian Supplement, Tifinagh, Ethiopic Extended, Cyrillic Extended-A" (also CJK radical supplement)

*3000*: (start of "CJK Symbols and Punctuation", some selections allowed)

**3004-3007, 3021-302F, 3031-303F**: (allowed "CJK Symbols and Punctuation")

**3040-D7FF**: "Hiragana, Katakana," more CJK ideograms, radicals, etc.

*D800-F8FF*: (This starts the [High](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UD800.pdf) and Low Surrogate Areas (number space needed for encodings), and [Private Use](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UE000.pdf))

**F900-FD3D, FD40-FDCF, FDF0-FE44, FE47-FFFD**: selections from "CJK Compatibility Ideographs," "Arabic Presentation Forms," etc.
**10000−1FFFD, 20000−2FFFD, 30000−3FFFD, 40000−4FFFD, 50000−5FFFD,
60000−6FFFD, 70000−7FFFD, 80000−8FFFD, 90000−9FFFD, A0000−AFFFD,
B0000−BFFFD, C0000−CFFFD, D0000−DFFFD, E0000−EFFFD**: [WG21/N3146](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3146.html) gives the rationale for these final ranges:

> The Supplementary Private Use Area extends from F0000 through 10FFFF; both [[AltId]](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/tr31-11.html#Alternative_Identifier_Syntax) and [[XML2008]](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn) disallow characters in that range.
>
> In addition, [[AltId]](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/tr31-11.html#Alternative_Identifier_Syntax) disallows, as non-characters, the last two code positions of each plane, i.e. every position of the form *P*FFFE or *P*FFFF, for any value of *P*.

The "Ranges of characters disallowed initially" from [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) Annex D.2 are **0300−036F, 1DC0−1DFF, 20D0−20FF, FE20−FE2F**.

With this [WG21/N3146](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3146.html) placed next to the Annex D of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), much can be inferred about how they line up.  For example, mathematical operators and punctuation seem to be not allowed.  I hope this sheds some light on "why" or "how" the allowed characters were chosen.

---

### TLDR; version

- Authoritative source for legal identifier characters is the C11 standard [ISO/IEC 9899:2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (See Annex D).
- This list is based on a technical report, [ISO/IEC TR 10176](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=37765), but with [modifications](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3146.html).

Comment: Great research.  It's a tad shocking how myriad, disparate, and undecipherable all these various sources are!

Answer (score 8):

[C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> #### 6.4.2 Identifiers
>
> **6.4.2.1 General**
> ...
> 3     Each universal character name in an identifier shall designate a character whose encoding
> in ISO/IEC 10646 falls into one of the ranges specified in D.1.<sup>71)</sup> The initial character
> shall not be a universal character name designating a character whose encoding falls into
> one of the ranges specified in D.2. An implementation may allow multibyte characters
> that are not part of the basic source character set to appear in identifiers; which characters
> and their correspondence to universal character names is implementation-defined.
>
> ...
>
> ---
>
> <sup>71) On systems in which linkers cannot accept extended characters, an encoding of the universal character
> name may be used in forming valid external identifiers. For example, some otherwise unused
> character or sequence of characters may be used to encode the \u in a universal character name.
> Extended characters may produce a long external identifier.</sup>
>
> ...
>
> ## Annex D
>
> ## (normative)
>
> ### Universal character names for identifiers
>
> 1     This clause lists the hexadecimal code values that are valid in universal character names
> in identifiers.
> **D.1 Ranges of characters allowed**
> 1     00A8, 00AA, 00AD, 00AF, 00B2−00B5, 00B7−00BA, 00BC−00BE, 00C0−00D6,
> 00D8−00F6, 00F8−00FF
> 2     0100−167F, 1681−180D, 180F−1FFF
> 3     200B−200D, 202A−202E, 203F−2040, 2054, 2060−206F
> 4     2070−218F, 2460−24FF, 2776−2793, 2C00−2DFF, 2E80−2FFF
> 5     3004−3007, 3021−302F, 3031−303F
> 6     3040−D7FF
> 7     F900−FD3D, FD40−FDCF, FDF0−FE44, FE47−FFFD
> 8     10000−1FFFD, 20000−2FFFD, 30000−3FFFD, 40000−4FFFD, 50000−5FFFD,
> 60000−6FFFD, 70000−7FFFD, 80000−8FFFD, 90000−9FFFD, A0000−AFFFD,
> B0000−BFFFD, C0000−CFFFD, D0000−DFFFD, E0000−EFFFD
> **D.2 Ranges of characters disallowed initially**
> 1     0300−036F, 1DC0−1DFF, 20D0−20FF, FE20−FE2F

Comment: could you at least drop a node what this means about his observations, since I guess not everyone is familiar with the encoding of each unicodation.

Comment: @dhein The answer to "and why" is "Because the standard says so". The only entity that can say why is the ISO. Generally standard organization don't have to justify their decisions. And I have not assumed any lack of knowledge, I said **if** (that means "for the case that the following is true" and not "the following is true") and I write that, as you said "I guess not everyone is familiar with the encoding of each unicodation", well, if you are not familiar with it, then you don't seem to know ISO/IEC 10646, as that standard explains it.

Comment: @Mecki: Well, I am not considering myself "everyone"... So it was a suggestion for the answer how to improve the quality of this answer. I also know that only the people (in this case the committee) making a decision are those who can say why they made a decision. Nonetheless that's what OP asked and since this answer wasn't leaving a note on it (either stating there is no such reason known to have been given, or mentioning the reason that was given) I was pointing it out. So I wasn't asking either of the 2 things. I was just leaving a suggestions for improving the answer as its missing these.

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned, the [C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) defines several allowed Ranges of Unicode characters.

- 00A8, 00AA, 00AD, 00AF, 00B2−00B5, 00B7−00BA, 00BC−00BE, 00C0−00D6, 00D8−00F6, 00F8−00FF
- 0100−167F, 1681−180D, 180F−1FFF
- 200B−200D, 202A−202E, 203F−2040, 2054, 2060−206F
- 2070−218F, 2460−24FF, 2776−2793, 2C00−2DFF, 2E80−2FFF
- 3004−3007, 3021−302F, 3031−303F
- 3040−D7FF
- F900−FD3D, FD40−FDCF, FDF0−FE44, FE47−FFFD
- 10000−1FFFD, 20000−2FFFD, 30000−3FFFD, 40000−4FFFD, 50000−5FFFD, 60000−6FFFD, 70000−7FFFD, 80000−8FFFD, 90000−9FFFD, A0000−AFFFD, B0000−BFFFD, C0000−CFFFD, D0000−DFFFD, E0000−EFFFD

This also means there are several ranges of characters excluded from usage.
From your examples:

- ☎ is `260E` and from the "Miscellaneous Symbols" block: `2600-26FF` which means youre missing out on [all of these](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2600.pdf)
- ❌ is `274C` and from the "Dingbats" block: `2700-27BF` which is [all of these](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2700.pdf) but some of them are allowed (`2776−2793`)
- ⇧ is `21E7` and from the "Arrows " block: `2190-21FF` which means youre missing out on [all of these](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2190.pdf)
- 〓 is `3013` and from the "CJK Symbols and Punctuation" block: `3000-303F` which is [all these](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U3000.pdf) but some of them are allowed.
- is `1F34E` and from the "Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs" block: `1F300-1F5FF` which is [all these](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf) and actually should work
   (maybe a `clang`problem? btw this is not displayed on my home computer (Ubuntu) but on my work PC (Win7))

Comment: So far this is the only answer that answers the question "why not".  This is the root of my confusion, and unless something earth shattering is presented.. This will take the bounty.

Comment: @alexgray, you are of course free to award the bounty to whomever you choose, but if indeed you had an interest in speculation on *why* the standard specifies what it does, as opposed to only *what* the standard specifies, then you would have gotten more answers addressing that point by raising it in your question.  Or even in comments.

Comment: @alexgray so now you gave one half of the bounty to john-bollinger and the other half to no one? interesting...

Comment: @TabascoEye No, I was super busy yesterday and didn't have a moment to award it to anybody!  (That 24-hour limit is pretty draconian, IMHO). `SE` seems to have divvied things up as they see fit, and doesn't look like I get to have any say in it, now.  

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for identifiers, which include macro names, is presented in section 6.4.2 of the C2011 standard, as interpreted in light of appendix D.1.  These provisions hold that every identifier may contain underscores, upper- and lower-case Latin letters, decimal digits, sequences of characters constituting "universal character names" (subject to limitations), *and any other character defined by the implementation*.

Universal character names (UCNs) are Unicode escape sequences similar to those provided by Java, Python, and some other languages: they start with a backslash (`\`), which is followed by a `u` or `U`, and either four or eight hexadecimal digits, respectively.  There are some limitations on the specific hex digit sequences that may be used, some general, others specific to identifier context.  Note, however, that *syntactically*, the only additional character that the provision for UCNs allows to appear in identifiers is the backslash; all the other characters that can appear in a UCN are allowed in identifiers outside of UCN context, too.

Thus, speaking syntactically and restricting the discussion to the characters that the standard requires to be allowed in identifiers, the underscore, (unaccented) Latin letters, decimal digits, and the backslash are the only characters that C requires must be supported in identifiers.  Support for the backslash is required only in the context of UCNs, and not all valid UCNs are allowed in identifiers.  Additionally, the standard does not require support for digits as the first characters of identifiers.

On the other hand, the standard is quite liberal in allowing "other implementation-defined characters" in identifiers, including as the first character.  Even decimal digits, which otherwise cannot be the first character in an identifier, could, in principle, be allowed at that position under this provision, at the discretion of the implementation.  If you want your code to be portable among implementations then you will avoid relying on this provision anywhere.  If you want to know which characters your particular implementation allows then you must consult its documentation.

Every standard-conforming implementation must document its behavior with respect to every detail the standard declares to be implementation defined.  For example, [GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior) specifies that the dollar sign (`$`) is allowed in identifiers on most target architectures.  You yourself linked to and quoted Clang's documentation of the same implementation-defined detail, which is more liberal -- it allows all the characters that can be represented in identifiers via UCNs to also be representable by UTF-8 byte sequences.  In many cases, if you display or print source code containing such byte sequences, they will be rendered as a single display character.