# Is dollar sign ($) allowed as a parameter or identifier in c?

Tags: c

I was looking at `sal.h` header in `c` and found that `$` is often used in procedures parameters. What is this? AFAIK, it is not allowed in `C`.

For example (from MS C/C++ Compiler Include\sal.h)

```
171  #define _Pre_z_            _Pre2_impl_(_$notnull,  _$zterm)
```

Comment: What says your compiler?

Comment: Which compiler?  It may be implementation-dependent..?

Comment: @axiac `c` compiler doesn't complain about. This is my curiosity, why it doesn't complain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What constitutes a "valid" C Identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319000/what-constitutes-a-valid-c-identifier)

Comment: @MartinJames I have this file in `MS C/C++` compiler include files.

Comment: @GulluButt I think what axiac meant was : which C compiler? There are several compilers available ...

Comment: Similar question about C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926394/in-variable-name

Answer (score 1):

The C standard specifies that identifiers may contain letters, digits, and the underscore. That's it. Some compilers (such as GCC) might also allow the use of the dollar sign, but they are doing so outside of the standard, so using this feature will make your program non-portable.

Comment: This dollar sign is problem for me. Can you suggest any work around. I am trying to compile c headers with a third party compiler and it does not recognize it. If I only change $ sign with something else, may be? what do you think?

Comment: Maybe this code isn't meant to be portable C. Sure, you could change the identifiers and it would probably compile, but there might be other GCC-specific or other non-portable stuff in it.