# Occurrences of question mark in C code

Tags: c, syntax, ternary-operator

I am doing a simple program that should count the occurrences of ternary operator ?: in C source code. And I am trying to simplify that as much as it is possible. So I've filtered from source code these things:

1. String literals "    "
2. Character constants ' '
3. Trigraph sequences ??=, ??(, etc.
4. Comments
5. Macros

And now I am only counting the occurances of questionmarks.

So my question question is: Is there any other symbol, operator or anything else what could cause problem - contain '?' ?

Let's suppose that the source is syntax valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you found all places where a question-mark is introduced and therefore eliminated all possible false-positives (for the ternary op). But maybe you eliminated too much: Maybe you want to count those "?:"'s that get introduced by macros; you dont count those. Is that what you intend? If that's so, you're done.

Comment: +1, I was about the post an almost identical answer. Preprocessing the code would be the easy option, counting `?:` once per macro definition it appears in would IMHO be the fair option.

Comment: yep, depends on what OP wants :-)

Comment: removing macros was one demand so this behaviour is correct :)

Answer (score 3):

Run your tool on preprocessed source code (you can get this by running e.g. `gcc -E`).  This will have done all macro expansions (as well as `#include` substitution), and eliminated all trigraphs and comments, so your job will become much easier.

Comment: +1 for using good already-existing software to eliminate the problem

Comment: definite +1. although OP has accepted what I wrote this could be what he or someone else in similar situations needs. it all comes down to what he/she wants to count.

Comment: calling gcc and other are not permited and availibility not guaranteed. Analyzator is Perl script...

Answer (score -1):

In K&R ANSI C the only places where a question mark can validly occur are:

1. String literals " "
2. Character constants ' '
3. Comments

Now you might notice macros and trigraph sequences are missing from this list.

I didn't include trigraph sequences since they are a compiler extension and not "valid C". I don't mean you should remove the check from your program, I'm trying to say you already went further then what's needed for ANSI C.

I also didn't include macros because when you're talking about a character that can occur in macros you can mean two things:

1. Macro names/identifiers
2. Macro bodies

The ? character can not occur in macro identifiers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369495/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-macro-names), and I see macro bodies as regular C code so the first list (string literals, character constants and comments*) should cover them too.

* Can macros validly contain comments? Because if I use this:

```
#define somemacro 15 // this is a comment
```

then `// this is a comment` isn't part of the macro. But what if I would compiler this C file with `-D somemacro="15 // this is a comment"`?

Comment: trigraph sequences are valid C. See 5.2.1.1 in [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: -1 This whole post is incorrect. And this is why you should refer to **ISO C** and not some K&R mumbo ANSI jumbo. Trigraphs are perfectly valid standard C. Read all about them in the C standard chapter 5.2.1.1 or in K&R **2nd** edition. Also for your information, K&R 1st and 2nd editions know nothing about // comments. They aren't valid K&R mumbo ANSI jumbo C.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am new to C, and I just worked through K&R __1st__ version. It was stupid for me to think that all that information (despite still being a good book) is still relevant.

Comment: If you are as new to C as you claim, shouldn't you think twice about answering at all?