# GNU g++ preprocessor/compiler: printf value

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

Hi im looking for a solution for GCC to printf a value which is calculated during compilation.

There is message pragmas but they can only print a user input string. what im looking for is a printf style output where i can input parameters.

**example**

```
printf("hi %s, my value is %d\n", "john", 15);
```

**example 2: searching solution for this**

```
void dummy(MyObjectReference & obj)
{
#if(sizeof(obj) != 512)
#pragma message "cannot build, your object size is not 512, it is %d", sizeof(obj)
#error "stop build"
#endif

  obj.do_stuff();

  return obj.get_result();
}
```

Comment: The code shown is C++, so I removed the C language tag.

Comment: i  suggest you to see this answer :[How can I use #pragma message() so that the message points to the file(lineno)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5966882)

Comment: In C++ you can do this with language constructs (not preprocessor)

Answer (score 4):

> Hi im looking for a solution for GCC to printf a value which is calculated during compilation.

You cannot do that with a standard [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/).

You could consider writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) providing, for example, some additional `#pragma` (or GCC builtin) doing what you want.

However, developing such a plugin might take you several weeks of efforts. You'll need to understand GCC internals to code that plugin. So look into [GCC resource](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/) center.

With C++11 or later, you might [use](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) `static_assert(sizeof(obj) == 512, "bad size of obj")` which works [*after*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) preprocessing (but won't display `sizeof(obj)` as an integer).

Comment: `static_assert` exists in C++11 as well. Note that before C++17, you have to provide a message as well (i.e. `static_assert(sizeof(obj) == 512, "unexpected obj size")`). But this won't solve OP's issue, since said message must be a string literal.

Comment: yes i work with static assertions (cpp14). but none of the messages printed in case of failure, be it pragmas, or assertion string, are able to format a string with int parameters as a simple printf.

so it should be possible, to tell me something like "static assertion failure, obj is not 512, its acutally just 496 or something.

Comment: You could consider extending GCC with your own plugin.