# Pass by reference behavior from ncurses

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, ncurses

I've recently started playing around with ncurses.
As far as I understand, C doesn't support passing by reference.

However, there are some functions that seem to exhibit such a behavior:

calling `getmaxyx(stdscr, maxRow, maxCol);` assigns the the number of rows and number of columns to `maxRow` and `maxCol` respectively. `getyx` seems to exhibit a similar behavior.

How is this done?

Comment: I Also fell for this trick. It seemed so much a function that it never occured to me to think it to be a macro. I often perceived people using CAPITALS (like suggested in this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369495/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-macro-names/369534#369534]) to express macros,but it seems not be a rule, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a direct function call, but a macro, take a look [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmaxyx):

> All of these interfaces are macros. A "&" is not necessary before the variables y and x.

For example:

```
#define getmaxyx(w, y, x)   (y) = getmaxy(w), (x) = getmaxx(w)
```