# Is it possible redefine #warning?

Tags: c

We use `#warning` to show compile message, like this:

```
#warning Are you sure it is correct?
```

Is is possible redefine the `#warning` and can choice if enable or disable it, like this:

```
#ifdef ACTIVE_MY_WARNING
#define #my_warning #warning
#else
#define #my_warning 
#endif
```

We can do it in C or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to redefine preprocessor keywords (`#if`, `#define`, `#ifdef`, etc).

Your best shot is to have a parser that can replace your code with:

```
#ifdef ACTIVE_MY_WARNING
#warning Are you sure it is correct?
#endif
```

Comment: If looking for a definitive proof of this, one might cite that *"ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 6.10/1 specifies the grammar of preprocessing directives, making explicit that macro names share the exact same rules as identifiers. 6.4.2.1/1 specifies the rules for identifiers."*  Thus, no `#`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369495/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-macro-names

Answer (score 0):

You tag it in C
and as per my knowledge there is no
preprocessor live #warning in c.

My question for you ans " We can do it in C or not? "
is No.