# what does + sign after variable mean?

Tags: c++, c

what will be the output of following code
`int x,a=3;

x=+ +a+ + +a+ + +5;

printf("%d  %d",x,a);`

ouput is: 11 3. I want to know how? and what does + sign after a means?

Comment: Why write code you don't understand ?

Comment: I am not sure how this gets parsed, but pretty sure the result is undefined.

Comment: @juanchopanza You are right, it is certainly undefined, but the first step is explaining to the OP how it gets parsed into pre or post-increments. Without that, the OP is right to wonder what it means and cannot know that it is undefined.

Comment: @PascalCuoq There's no post or pre increment in that code.

Comment: @vard there is no `#define +a+ a`. I have run this code in turbo c.

Comment: @cnicular Oh, good, then it has no reason to be undefined.

Comment: @cnicutar are you sure? if not, how could it get parsed in a way that compiles?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Actually, I think it is defined. There are no increments in this code.

Comment: @cnicutar hmm, I an mot so sure. `int a{0}; a + + 5;` leaves `a` as `0`

Comment: @juanchopanza *int a{0}; a + + 5; leaves a as 0* Which proves my point. No increment ;)

Comment: @cnicutar yes, not increments, somebody else had said the extra `+` signs are superfluous, which is not the case.

Comment: @So how are the `+` not superfluous since you can drop them without changing the outcome ?

Comment: @juanchopanza: are you sure you got the meaning of superfluous right?

Comment: @LieRyan yes, superfluous if fine, but I was obviously confused about other stuff :-)

Comment: @vard see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369495/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-macro-names

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think DrYap has it right.

```
x = + + a + + + a + + + 5;
```

is the same as:

```
x = + (+ a) + (+ (+ a)) + (+ (+ 5));
```

The key points here are:

1) c, c++ don't have + as a postfix operator, so we know we have to interpret it as a prefix

2) monadic + binds more tightly (is higher precedence) than dyadic +

Funny isn't it ? If these were - signs it wouldn't look so strange. Monadic +/- is just a leading sign, or to put it another way, "+x" is the same as "0+x".

Comment: yeah, that make sense. There are spaces between + signs but if you remove spaces it shows compilation error:`Lvalue required`.

Comment: Yes, because if you remove the space between `+ +`, you get a single `++` (increment operator) instead of two plus signs.

Comment: `+x` is supposed to be like `0+x` for whatever `0` exists for the type of `x`, but there's no such guarantee under overloading. It could be called the "decay operator" because it returns a pure value even if its operand is an lvalue. For example, `++ + a` is illegal except for overloads, and will conventionally not increment `a`.

Comment: Good points. The overloading point only applies to c++. The "pure value" point should be true for c and c++. Feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 13):

The + after a just gets seen as a + before the next value. If you use consistent spacing it is  the same as:

```
x = + + a + + + a + + + 5;
```

But not all the +s are necessary so it will act the same as doing:

```
x = a + a + 5;
```

The value of a is unchanged because you have never used the incrementing operator which is ++ with no white space between the two + symbols. + and ++ are two separate operators.

Comment: I would add that C has a unary `+`, for symmetry with the unary minus `-`, and that this is what is used here. No-one knows what the unary plus is for except confusing programmers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s50et82s(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: but in this case it is not happening as value of a is not incremented. There are 3 + signs before second a.

Comment: What do you mean is not happening?

Comment: @user980089: "is not incremented" You know that "+5" means "5", right? So "+a" means "a". "+ + a" is not the same thing as "++a".

Comment: @PascalCuoq it has at least one use; see my comment to Julian's answer above.

Answer (score 3):

The code seems to be equivalent to:

`x= (+(+(a)))+ (+ (+(a)))+ (+(+(5)));`

I.e. `x = a + a + 5`. Which is 11. You know that you can put + or - sign before number, right? Now those `+` merely indicate sign of variable. Since sign is `+`, variable remains unchanged I.e. "+5" means "5", so "+a" means "a", and "+ +a" means "+(+a)" which means "a". In same fashion you could write `x = + + + 3 + + + + 3 + + + + 5`. Or `x = - + + - 3 + - + - 3 - - + 5;`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `+` operators are never two next to each other but always separated by a white space the statement 
`x=+ +a+ + +a+ + +5;` is actually read as

`x=+ (nothing)+a+(nothing) +(nothing) +a+(nothing) +(nothing) +5;`

so basically the final equation becomes of the sort
`x=a+a+5;` and hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

x=+ +a+ + +a+ + +5 : This is equivalent to

x =  x=+ +a+ + +a+ + +5  or 
we can write it as  x = + (+ a) + (+ (+ a)) + (+ (+ 5))
and the +'s are only indicating the signs which will be finally evaluated as 
x = a + a + 5.