# Structure pointer operator conjecture (theory)

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, struct, operators

Pointers to structures are used so often that there is a special operator for it: ->.  The below expressions are equivalent:

```
(*x).y
 x->y
```

Would it be fair to think of this operator simply as preprocessor macro defined as such:

`#define (x)-> (*(x).)`

Why or why not? Or was it coded as a operator from the start - and how would this be different / advantageous?

Just curious.

Comment: Yuck. Can't be since `(x)->` does not a valid macro name make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **The below expressions are equivalent:?**

```
(*x).y
 x->y
```

**Yes**, Both are two different ways to access structure member `y`.

`(*x).y` operator is `.` DOT that works with value variable `Element selection by reference`. that the reason `*` used. means `x` is pointer to struct.

`x->y` operator `->` is used called `Element selection through pointer`. This work with pointer to struct. that is the reason `*` not used this time.

Both works same.

> **Would it be fair to think of this operator simply as preprocessor macro defined as such:**

```
#define (x)-> (*(x).)
```

**No**   First it give an **error:** *macro names must be identifiers*. This error is because we can't have `->` operator as macro name.

a [*valid macro name*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369495/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-macro-names?answertab=votes#tab-top) can be:

> Macro names should only consist of alphanumeric characters and underscores, i.e. 'a-z', 'A-Z', '0-9', and '_', and the first character should not be a digit. Some preprocessors also permit the dollar sign character '$', but you shouldn't use it; unfortunately I can't quote the C standard since I don't have a copy of it.

Also, note `->` and `.` are differences operators as I state above. also their precedence are  different so its bad idea to replace one operator with other.

> **Valid macros to access struct elements:**

Additionally I would like to share today only i came to know that most C header files. Defined macros like:

```
#define S(x)  ((x).y)
```

for specific strcut element.

Notice `(x)`  parenthesis around `x` is to overwrite precedence of `*` over `.` . By default `.` DOT has higher precedence over `*`  So that it can be use for pointer and simple variable. Below my example will be helpful I think.

```
#define S(x)  ((x).y)
typedef struct {
 int y;
}X;
X *x;
X b;
int main(){
 S(*x);
 S(b);     
}
```

**EDIT:**
Better Option

I am extending my idea to access strcut elements, I defined new macro:

```
#define S(x,y)  ((x).y)
typedef struct {
 int a;
}X;
X *x;
X b;
int main(){
 S(*x,a);
 S(b,a);
}
```

Not its not more for specif elements via macros.

Hope at-least OP love it :)

Comment: Let me know if you have confusion regarding `S(x)  ((x).y)` macro.

Comment: @GManNickG its not mine I saw in header files. But I am true. Do you have better idea **?** Please share with us.

Comment: @GManNickG Haa! I just saw most fantastic questions are your on SO.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't propose any ideas because there's no problem to solve. :) People should just use `x.y` explicitly.

Comment: @GManNickG I was editing in my answer while you here commenting I guess. Please review again I hope I could improve a bit. And by the chance its as you commented.

Comment: So you can pass a pointer like (*x) as an argument to a macro?  That makes sense.  Wicked answer, cool.

Answer (score 4):

> Would it be fair to think of this operator simply as preprocessor macro defined as such:

No.

> Why or why not?

The `->` operator has some specific semantics that cannot be enforced with a macro (which is a simple text substitution).  Namely, the left-hand operand *must* be a pointer to a struct or union type, and the right-hand operand must be a member of the struct or union type, and the result of the expression must be an lvalue.  You cannot enforce those rules with a macro.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be fair to think of this operator simply as preprocessor macro defined as such:

No, it wouldn't.

> Why or why not?

Because it's not a macro. It's a distinct operator defined in the language, that appears to be providing syntactic sugar for another functionality.