# #define with member from structured pointer

Tags: c, macros

I have a structure like :

```
struct spidev_data {
  int busy;
  int irq;
};
```

And I just want to access a member ( like spidev->busy ) by a define, so I try this:

```
#define BUSY spidev->busy
```

But it does not work...

Can someone tell me how to do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: And spidev is a pointer to the structure?

Comment: `#define BUSY(x) x->busy`

Comment: Always include the error message! And a small bit of code showing the error. The `#define` by itself will not give an error, you get the error when using it.

Comment: how about `int BUSY( spidev_data* p ){ return p->busy; }` ?

Comment: @stijn: you probably want an `inline` before that, and for C a `struct` before `spidev_data`

Comment: Yes spidev is a pointer to the structure ! Your answer is cool BLUEPIXY , but i prefer avoid using argument in my macro...

Comment: @MSalters my macro doesn't work because she's raising a seg fault :/ and when i use directly spidev->busy, i don't have a seg fault.

Comment: @RaphaëlPoggi: Then show us **both** snippets of code. Since the `#define` is a simple text replacement, I find your claim very hard to believe.

Comment: `spidev` initialize before use?

Comment: This post is a useless waste of time without a SSCCE (sscce.org)

Comment: @RaphaëlPoggi [Read my this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167542/structure-pointer-operator-conjecture-theory/15167955#15167955)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this

```
spidev_data *spidev = /* ... new or malloc ... */;

BUSY = 1;
```

But more elegant is

```
#define BUSY(X) (X)->busy

...

BUSY(spidev) = 1;
```

because it is not specially for an object.

Comment: I think that it should be `(X)->busy`

Comment: I'd recommend to add parentheses around the 2nd occurrence o `X` in the `#define`.