# Why is my compiler denying the compilation of this program?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#define NO-EXTER
typedef int snow;
typedef void shells;
typedef char byteUendedLin;
typedef short ANDNOOP;

shells drawsnake(snow size, byteUendedLin *Height__Maskm_, ANDNOOP &Filesz_9Err);

snow main(snow args, byteUendedLin**LOC[])
{
    byteUendedLin *ANDNOEXpfortopoflist[1];
    snow nCagado;
    byteUendedLin *NOTOPS2s3_filenam;
    drawsnake(nCagado, ANDNOEXpfortopoflist, NOTOPS2s3_filenam);
}

shells drawsnake(snow size, byteUendedLin *Height__Maskm_, ANDNOOP &Filesz_9Err);
{
    ANDNOOP Firstbad = 300;
    if(size(Height_Maskm_) >= Firstbad)
    {
        return;
    }
}

}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4


Line 10: error: missing whitespace after the macro name
In function 'snow main(snow, byteUendedLin***)':
Line 13: error: cannot convert 'byteUendedLin**' to 'byteUendedLin*' 
    for argument '2' to 'shells drawsnake(snow, byteUendedLin*, ANDNOOP&)'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

It seems like the error makes no sense ... what does it mean cannot convert byteUendedLin to a pointer? I don't get it!

PS: Forgive the format; I was using typedefs as experimentation.

Comment: It also seems like the program makes no sense... please format it properly :)

Comment: This seems to be the problem: [What are the valid characters for macro names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369495/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-macro-names)

Comment: Also, in the future, you should probably specify what operating system and compiler you're using. There's a lot of variation in the C++ implementations.

Comment: Lots of errors (in addition to what others said): remove the ";" after "ANDNOOP &Filesz_9Err)"  Next, "Height_Maskm_" is not the same name as you declared. The prototype for "drawsnake" doesn't match.

Comment: Please be more specific what part of the error messages you do not understand. They are quite clear as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

`ANDNOEXpfortopoflist` is an array of pointers, which decays to a pointer to a pointer because you pass it as an argument. See [*How do I use arrays in C++?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

You cannot convert `T**` to `T*` because `T**` is not convertible to `T*`. They are two completely different and unrelated data types. You can dereference a `T**` to get a `T*`, though, using the unary `*` operator.

See [this tutorial](http://codepuppy.co.uk/cpptuts/Beginning/pointers.php) for an introduction to pointers.

---

P.S. your program also exhibits undefined behaviour because the identifier `Height__Maskm_` is reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is:

```
#define NO-EXTER
```

This defines a macro `NO` with the value `-EXTER`. The compiler wants a space between the macro name and the definition.

Either write:

```
#define NO -EXTER
```

or:

```
#define NO_EXTER
```

Another problem is your definition of `main()`:

```
snow main(snow args, byteUendedLin**LOC[])
```

When you convert the typedefs, that's equivalent to:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv[])
```

but the standard requires:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

or using your typedefs and variable names:

```
snow main(snow args, byteUendedLin **LOC)
```