# Invalid characters in C preprocessors/macros?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

What are the different **invalid characters** that I am not allowed use in a **macro** ?
It seems that `#define TE$T 8` is working, so `$` is valid.
Does somebody have a list of the invalid characters ? (or on the contrary the list of the valid ones).

Comment: A macro identifier may not start with a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your compiler that allows usage of `$` as an identifier. It's not standard and you shouldn't expect other compilers to provide it or your compiler to allow it, if you compile with `-pedantic` or similar.

In the C11 draft's common extension appendix:

> **J.5.2 Specialized identifiers**
>
> **1**   Characters other than the underscore _, letters, and digits, that
>   are not part of the basic source character set (*such as the dollar sign $*, or characters in national character sets) may appear in an identifier (6.4.2).

**Section 6.4.2** shows what characters *every* conforming compiler has to
support:

```
6.4.2 Identifiers
6.4.2.1 General
Syntax 1         identifier:
                 identifier-nondigit
                 identifier identifier-nondigit
                 identifier digit
         identifier-nondigit:
                 nondigit
                 universal-character-name
                 other implementation-defined characters
         nondigit: one of
                _ a b            c    d    e    f     g    h    i    j     k    l    m
                    n o          p    q    r    s     t    u    v    w     x    y    z
                    A B          C    D    E    F     G    H    I    J     K    L    M
                    N O          P    Q    R    S     T    U    V    W     X    Y    Z
         digit: one of
                0 1        2     3    4    5    6     7    8    9
```

You should restrict yourself to those.

Answer (score 1):

Macro names should only consist of alphanumeric characters and underscores, i.e. 'a-z', 'A-Z', '0-9', and '_', and the first character should not be a digit. Some preprocessors also permit the dollar sign character '$', but you shouldn't use it.

Also have look on this... [What are the valid characters for macro names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369495/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-macro-names)

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that `#define TE$T 8` is working, so `$` is valid.

That's not true.  `$` is NOT a valid character for identifiers in standard C. Some compilers, e.g, GCC , allows `$` in identifiers as an extension. (See [Dollar Signs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs))

So you are asking the wrong question, there's nothing special for names in macros, all the preprocessor does is text replacement.

Comment: Wrong! It is not required by the standard, but the standard very well allows such additional characters, so for a specific implementation (e.g. gcc) they are very well valid characters.

Answer (score 0):

Consider somefille.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NAM$ "SomeName"
int main(void)
{
printf("Name - %s\n",NAM$);

return 0;
}
```

Compiling the above with

```
gcc -pedantic somefille.c -o somefille
```

gives you

```
somefille.c:2:9: warning: '$' in identifier or number [enabled by default]
 #define NAM$ "SomeName"
```

This [[ page ]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says.

> -pedantic
>       Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other
>   programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++. For ISO C, follows the
>   version of the ISO C standard specified by any -std option used.

As per the strict standard the macro name must have no spaces in it, and it must conform to the same naming rules that C variables follow: Only letters, digits, and the underscore ( _ ) character can be used, and the first character cannot be a digit.

The problem is that various compilers do not comply with this. An example is gcc which I mentioned above.

Having said that, below rules are still obeyed:

1. A macro name must not begin with a number, if you violate this you may get an error like :

   ```
   error: macro names must be identifiers
   ```
2. A macro name must not contain spaces. For instance `#define FULL NAME "Your name"` gives you :

   ```
   error: ‘NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   ```

Comment: Wrong! It is not required by the standard, but the standard very well allows such additional characters, so for a specific implementation (e.g. gcc) they are very well valid characters (not specific for macro names, btw.).

Comment: @Olaf : I did mention "strict ISO C" which doesn't allow anything other than standard features IMHO.

Comment: Please read the cited paragraph carefully. The standard explicitly allows additional characters. Despite extensions which often violate the standard.